# I/p frequency is 8000 Hz then why why does the output of following code shows peak at 2000 Hz?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

The i/p frequency is 8000 Hz. Why does the o/p of the following code shows, a peak in spectrogram at 2000 Hz? I am new to the spectrogram, can anyone please explain?

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


time = np.linspace(start = 0, stop = 10, num = 100000) 

t1 = time[0,]
t2 = time[1,]

del_t = t2-t1

fs = 1e4 #np.ceil(1/del_t)

ip_f = 8000

x = np.sin(2*np.pi*ip_f*time) 

# plt.plot(time,x)

op_f, op_t, op_Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs)

plt.pcolormesh(op_t, op_f, op_Sxx, shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

If your sample rate is only 10 kHz then 8 kHz is above the [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) (5 kHz). It will [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) to 2 kHz, as you have seen.

Comment: I modified the code by making fs = 2e4, which is below Nyquist frequency (10 kHz). Now, the figure shows, a peak at 4000 Hz and the x-scale is shortened from 10 seconds to 5-seconds. Can you please explain what goes wrong?

Comment: Change `num = 100000` to `num = 200000` to increase the sample rate to 20 kHz, and set `fs = 1 / del_t` instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, Could you please tell me the logic, how did you find that I should change the "num" values to obtain correct answer.

Comment: When you define `time` using `linspace` you are implicitly defining the sample rate, e.g. 100000 samples over 10s gives a sample interval (`del_t`) of 0.1 ms, which is equivalent to a 10 kHz sample rate (`fs`). By doubling the number of samples to 200000 you double the sample rate to 20 kHz.